# Error FS3021 Unexpected exception from provided type 'FSharp

Tags: .net, f#, data-access-layer

I created F# Console Application (.NET 4.7.2) and then added Nuget package to FSharp.Data.SqlProvider

Then I wrote this code in F#

```
module File1

//#r "FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll"
open System
open FSharp.Data.Sql

let [<Literal>] dbVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER

let [<Literal>] connString = "Server=localhost;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True"

let [<Literal>] useOptTypes  = true

let [<Literal>] indivAmount = 1000

type sql =
    SqlDataProvider<
        dbVendor,
        connString,
        IndividualsAmount = indivAmount,
        UseOptionTypes = useOptTypes>

let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()
```

After I do build all I am getting error, what this error means?

> Error FS3021  Unexpected exception from provided type
>   'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlDataProvider,DatabaseVendor="0",ConnectionString="Server=localhost;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True",UseOptionTypes="True"+dataContext'
>   member 'GetMethods': The type provider
>   'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: The design-time
>   type 'System.Data.IDbConnection' utilized by a type provider was not
>   found in the target reference assembly set '[tgt assembly
>   FSharp.Data.SqlProvider, Version=1.1.62.0, Culture=neutral;  tgt
>   assembly mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;  tgt assembly FSharp.Core,
>   Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; 
>   tgt assembly System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;  tgt assembly System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089; 
>   tgt assembly System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;  tgt assembly System.ValueTuple,
>   Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51]'.
>   You may be referencing a profile which contains fewer types than those
>   needed by the type provider you are
>   using.    ConsoleApplicationF C:\Users\UserXXX\source\repos\ConsoleApplicationF\ConsoleApplicationF\File1.fs  22  Active

When I do the same for NET CORE I get another error

> FS3033    The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an
>   error in the context of provided type
>   'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlDataProvider,DatabaseVendor="0",ConnectionString="Server=localhost;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True"',
>   member 'GetDataContext'. The error: Method 'System.String
>   tryGetConnectionString(Boolean, System.String, System.String,
>   System.String)' not found in type ''. This method may be missing
>   in the types available in the target assemblies

Comment: The above for me works in VS 2017 targeting `netcoreapp2.2`. Check that Microsoft.NETCore.App is being pulled in as an SDK dependency as that should contain System.Data. I did get a different error when trying to run from command line though.

Comment: I will correct question and enhance it with NET Core and NET 4.7.2